# Addition of distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Give an example of discrete random variables ξ, η, ζ such that $F_{ξ}$ ≡ $F_{η}$, but $F_{ξ+ ζ}$ $\ne$ $F_{η + ζ}$.

Comment: Do you want an answer or a hint?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Any help, maybe answer - if it's possible

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a start and elaborate further if need be.

Consider the space $\Omega=\{ 1,2 \}$ with the probability:

$$ \mathbb{P}(\{1\}), \mathbb{P}(\{2\})=\frac{1}{2} $$

Define $\xi:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as:
$$  \xi(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & ;x=1 \\ 1 &; x=2 \end{cases} $$

And $\eta :\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as:

$$  \eta(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & ;x=1 \\ 0 &; x=2 \end{cases} $$

Verify that they will satisfy what you need from $\eta$ and $\xi$, and see what happens for $\zeta:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where:

$$ \zeta(x)= \begin{cases} -1 & ;x=1 \\ 0 &; x=2 \end{cases} $$

Then:

$$ F_{\zeta+\eta}(x)=\begin{cases}0 &; x<0 \\ 1& ;x\geq 0 \end{cases} \quad \text{and} \quad F_{\zeta+\xi}(x)= \begin{cases} 0 & ;x<-1 \\
\frac{1}{2} & ; -1\leq x<1 \\ 
1 & ;x\geq 1 \end{cases} $$

Comment: Well, that perfect, but, the distribution func is  $F_{ξ}: R\rightarrow‎ [0,1]$
$F_{ξ}(x) = P\{ω ∣ ξ(ω) \leq x\}$. Your example seems to be not good enough, am I right?

Comment: Your writing is unclear to me. Are you saying you think $F_\xi \neq F_\eta$?

Comment: I don't really understand, why it works for $F_{ξ}=F{η}$, but doesn't work for sum. I mean, why $F_{ξ+ζ}  ≠ F_{η+ζ} $?

Comment: I've added a complete example in an edit. Are you asking why can there be such an example, or why the specific example I gave works?

Comment: Why your example works

Comment: Checked your edit, does it matter $F_{ζ+η}(x)$ or $ F_{η+ζ}(x)$?

Comment: Since $\eta+\zeta=\zeta+\eta$, it does not. For any $\omega$, they are real numbers.

Comment: Excuse me, but what is the $χ[0,∞)$? I just started learning Probability theory.

Comment: The characteristic function of that interval. I rewrote it again more explicitly.